# Mysterious file corruption issues after several hours of use

Tags: ssd, filesystems, file-corruption

I built a desktop computer a few days ago and have noticed multiple instances of file corruption. A video game crashed twice, reporting file corruption after several hours of use, though it verified the checksum during installation. A similar thing happened to qBittorrent two times: a force recheck does not return any errors immediately, but after a few hours/days another recheck will send qBittorrent redownloading several pieces of files. UPDATE: the problem is reproducible as force recheck on qBittorrent once every few hours will lead to several files missing 16MB of data. This only happens after some time and an immediate second recheck will report that all files are intact. Switching to a dual boot Ubuntu system also produces the same issue on qBittorrent.

I checked my SSD with `CrystalDiskInfo`, which did not return any errors. I'm wondering: what else could cause these recurring anomalies? I suspect that a faulty SSD is the culprit but would like to rule out other factors.

Additional system info:

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro
CPU: Ryzen 5 3600G
Motherboard: Gigabyte B550M Aorus Elite
SSD: Predator GM3500 M.2 SSD 2TB
```

Other specs (RAM, PSU) should be irrelevant here.

Full SSD info below:

---

### (01) Predator SSD GM3500 2TB

```
           Model : Predator SSD GM3500 2TB
        Firmware : 42BFU6MG
   Serial Number : PSBF53160200514
       Disk Size : 2048.4 GB
       Interface : NVM Express
        Standard : NVM Express 1.3
   Transfer Mode : PCIe 3.0 x2 | PCIe 3.0 x4
  Power On Hours : 68 hours
  Power On Count : 11 times
      Host Reads : 773 GB
     Host Writes : 484 GB
     Temperature : 45 C (113 F)
   Health Status : good (100 %)
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., TRIM, VolatileWriteCache
    Drive Letter : C: D:

  ID RawValues(6) Attribute Name
  01 000000000000 Critical Warning
  02 00000000013D Composite Temperature
  03 000000000064 Available Spare
  04 00000000000A Available Spare Threshold
  05 000000000000 Percentage Used
  06 00000018C280 Data Units Read
  07 0000000F83DA Data Units Written
  08 000000970F57 Host Read Commands
  09 0000008A9174 Host Write Commands
  0A 0000000000AE Controller Busy Time
  0B 00000000000B Power Cycles
  0C 000000000044 Power On Hours
  0D 000000000006 Unsafe Shutdowns
  0E 000000000000 Media and Data Integrity Errors
  0F 000000000000 Number of Error Information Log Entries
```

Comment: CrystalDiskInfo should have told you if there was a problem with the SSD.  Perhaps you have a bad cable?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It's an M.2 drive, so perhaps one of the M.2 slots on the motherboard is faulty. I will switch it to a different slot and see what happens.

Comment: Reseat RAM and SSD connections. Check cables for solid connection and route them away from anything electrically noisy, e.g., neon lighting. Check settings *per* manual: https://www.manua.ls/gigabyte/b550m-ds3h/manual Intermittent issues are hard to track down, though. *sigh*

Comment: A decent SSD should not go bad in days. Mine last years.  Build a test Virtual Machine and see if files are deleted there as well. If so: likely hardware. If not: likely something in your OS build.

Comment: Fist step should be to actually demonstrate the 'silent' corruption. Until that, this is a wild goose chase. And also rather than stating SMART is fine, I think it should be obvious you include the actual SMART report.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I moved the SSD to a different M.2 slot, which is pretty far away from other component in the case. Problem still persists, unfortunately.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen The question is updated: I reproduced the qBittorrent recheck problem twice. Each time it tells me I'm missing 16MB pieces in several files and redownloads them. SMART info is also included.

Comment: @John I thought that a guest VM might be affected by the file system issues in its host, so I installed a dual boot Ubuntu system and setup qBittorrent again. A force recheck after a few hours has again led to an incomplete download for both torrents. I suppose I should test it using a different SSD since changing the OS does not help.

Comment: Yeah, but you'd need some confirmation it happens with random files, not just torrents, it might as well be a torrent thing. Anyway, you could replace SSD to rule out the current one. SMART looks fine BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Problem finally resolved after a few days.

The culprit was the motherboard. Swapping the M.2 drive for a different one (and a fresh OS install) did not fix it, but swapping the motherboard did. No longer are mysteriously corrupted torrents observed.

I suspect this might be a southbridge IO controller issue. Perhaps I was unlucky enough to get a defective motherboard with a problem hard to detect in the QC process.